# Do I need to have IE10 installed in order to use content="ie10" in HTA?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hta, x-ua-compatible

Some of the CSS styling I'm doing within my .hta requires the line `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10" />` at the top of the file in order to display the CSS correctly.

I'm wondering, if I run this .hta on a computer that has only IE 8 installed, will the line `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10" />` still work? I'm guessing not but would love to hear from you.

If not, can you suggest an alternative ... am I stuck with IE8 styles for them?

Comment: IE10 is not IE8. A meta-tag does not change this.

Answer (score 1):

That meta tag is not going to make IE8 behave like IE10, however you could use a library like:

- [CSS3pie](http://css3pie.com/)
- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

and others, to extend some features back, sometimes to IE6.

Do some searching for more libraries if these don't do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31910907/825757) is correct. That meta tag won't force IE 8 to behave like IE 10. However, I would recommend using another mode for all versions of IE. You should use is `IE=edge`, ie:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Edge mode tells Internet Explorer to display content in the highest mode available. With Internet Explorer 8, this is equivalent to IE8 mode.

If you use `IE=10` and view the site in IE 8, IE 8 won't understand that mode and disregard it and then pick the mode IE believes is the best. This could be IE 8 mode or compatibility mode. Typically, you want to avoid compatibility mode.